# Bibliography doesn't appear

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am currently writing my PhD dissertation and I am having trouble including my bibliography within it. I tried many different methods (changing the parameters of compilation, using the packages `natbib` or `bibtex`, `\nocite{*}`, ...) but nothing seems to work. I tried a minimal version of my latex and it worked out, however when including the entire preamble of the code the bibliography doesn't show up.

Here is the preamble of my code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, openany]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{dsfont}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx} % For commande \includegraphics
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor} %% To color in violet the text
\frenchspacing
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos} % to place elements in the page
\usepackage{multicol} % To write summary in two columns-mode
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{calc} % To calculate textwidth
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
%\RequirePackage{geometry}% That nicely create a one-page template
%\geometry{textheight=150ex,textwidth=40em,top=30pt,headheight=30pt,headsep=30pt,inner=80pt}
\usepackage{tikz} %% Make the square.
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\pagestyle{plain}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=false, %set true if you want colored links
    linktoc=all,     %set to all if you want both sections and subsections linked
    linkcolor=black,  %choose some color if you want links to stand out
}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\usepackage{epsfig}

\usepackage{natbib} % Bibliographie avancée (parenthèses, citep...)
\usepackage{hyperref} % Liens hypertextes, signets PDF
  \hypersetup{urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,colorlinks=true} 

%  \newcommand{\textcite}[1]{(#1)}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{aiaa}
\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you run `bibtex` at all? Off-Topic: The `epsfig` packages not needed nowadays and you're loading `hyperref` twice, don't do that!

Comment: Should I run the bibtex itself or is it sufficient to compile my .tex using "Latex + Bibtex + Latex(*2)"? Thanks for this information.

Comment: The second way!

Comment: Off-topic: Since you're loading the `graphicx` package, there can be no good reason for loading `epsfig` as well. Also, don't load `hyperref` twice, and do consolidate the two `\hypersetup` instructions.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I did compile using "Latex + Bibtex + Latex(*2)", but it didn't work out...

Answer (score 1):

Well, your question is not very clear. For example you missed to add some bib entrys to your question.

I build a MWE, included a `bib` file with package `filecontents` into the MWE and moved your both calls of package `hyperref` to be the last called package. I commented out the first call of `hyperref` and `\hypersetup`.

Because I'm not sure if you use `latex` or `pdflatex` to compile, I choosed `pdflatex` and therefore commented out `epsfig`.

With the following MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Wren,
  author  = "Wren C. and Azarbayejani A.",
  title   = {Pfinder: real-time tracking of the human body},
  journal = {IEEE Trans. Pattern Anal. Mach. Intell.},
  number  = {7},
  year    = {1997},
  volume  = {19},
  pages   = {780-785},
}
@InProceedings{Kim,
  author    = "Kim H. and Sakamoto R. and Kitahara I. and 
               Toriyama T. and Kogure K. ",
  title     = {Robust foreground extraction technique using Gaussian 
               family model and multiple thresholds},
  booktitle = {Asian Conference on Computer Vision, ACC 2007},
  OPTpages  = {758-768},
  year      = {2007},
  OPTmonth  = {Nov.},
}
@InProceedings{Stauffer,
  author    = "Stauffer C. and Grimson E. ",
  title     = {Adaptive background mixture models for real-time tracking}, 
  booktitle = {IEEE Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition, CVPR},
  OPTpages  = {246-252},
  year      = {1999},
}
@InProceedings{Elgammal,
  author    = " Elgammal, Ahmed and David Harwood and Larry Davis",
  title     = {Non-parametric model for background subtraction}, 
  booktitle = {Computer Vision ECCV 2000},
  OPTpages  = {751-767},
  year      = {2000},
}
@InProceedings{Mittal,
  author    = "Mittal, Anurag and Nikos Paragios",
  title     = {Motion-based background subtraction using adaptive kernel density estimation }, 
  booktitle = {Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition, CVPR 2004},
  OPTpages  = {704-711},
  year      = {2004},
  OPTvolume = {2},
  OPTmonth  = {June},
}
@Article{K,
  author  = "Kim K. and Chalidabhongswe T.H and Harwood D.",
  title   = {Real-time foreground-background segmentation using codebook model},
  journal = {Real  Time Imaging},
  number  = {3},
  year    = {2005},
  volume  = {11},
  pages   = {172-185},
}
@InProceedings{Doshi,
  author    = "A. Doshi and M. Trivedi ",
  title     = {Hybrid cone-cylinder codebook model for foreground 
               detection with shadow and highlight suppression}, 
  booktitle = {Video and Signal Based Surveillance,AVSS '06},
  OPTpages  = {764-771},
  year      = {2006},
  OPTmonth  = {Nov.},
}
@Article{Hu,
   author =   " H. Hu and L. Xu and H. Zhao",
   title =   {A spherical codebook in YUV color space for moving object detection},
   journal =   {Sensor Lett.},
   number = {1},
   year =   {2012},
   volume =   {10},
   pages =   {177-189},
}
@InProceedings{Sigari,
  author    = "Sigari, Mohamad Hoseyn and Mahmood Fathy",
  title     = {Real-time background modeling/subtraction using two-layer codebook model}, 
  booktitle = {International MultiConference of Engineering and Computer Scientists},
  OPTpages  = {764-771},
  volume    = {1},
  year      = {2008},
  OPTmonth  = {Nov.},
}
@Article{Barnich,
  author  = "Barnich, Olivier and Marc Van Droogenbroeck",
  title   = {Vibe: A universal background subtraction algorithm for video sequences},
  journal = {IEEE Transaction on Image Processing},
  number  = {6},
  year    = {2011},
  volume  = {20},
  pages   = {1709-1724},
}
@InProceedings{Lin,
  author    = "Geng-Cheng Lin and SSheng-Chih Yang and Chuin-Mu Wang and Che-Fu Lin",
  title     = {Background Subtraction Based on Codebook Model and Texture Feature}, 
  booktitle = {International Symposium on Computer, Consumer and control},
  OPTpages  = {498-501},
  volume    = {1},
  year      = {2016},
  OPTmonth  = {Nov.},
}
@InProceedings{Badal,
  author    = "Tapas Badal and Neeta Nain and Mushtaq Ahmed and Vishakha Sharma",
  title     = {An Adaptive Codebook Model for Change Detection with Dynamic Background}, 
  booktitle = {11th International Conference on Signal-Image Technology and Internet-Based Systems },
  OPTpages  = {110-116},
  volume    = {1},
  year      = {2015},
  OPTmonth  = {Nov.},
}
@Article{Bouwmans,
  author  = "Thierry Bouwmans",
  title   = {Traditional and recent approaches in background modeling 
             for foreground detection: An overview},
  journal = {COMPUTERSCIENCE REVIEW11},
  number  = {2},
  year    = {2014},
  volume  = {12},
  pages   = {31-66},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, openany]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{dsfont}

\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx} % For commande \includegraphics
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor} %% To color in violet the text
\frenchspacing
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos} % to place elements in the page
\usepackage{multicol} % To write summary in two columns-mode
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{calc} % To calculate textwidth
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
%\RequirePackage{geometry}% That nicely create a one-page template
%\geometry{textheight=150ex,textwidth=40em,top=30pt,headheight=30pt,headsep=30pt,inner=80pt}
\usepackage{tikz} %% Make the square.
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\pagestyle{plain}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

%\usepackage{epsfig}  % <=========================================================

%\usepackage{natbib} % Bibliographie avancée (parenthèses, citep...)

%\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} % <================================================
%\hypersetup{
    %colorlinks=false, %set true if you want colored links
    %linktoc=all,     %set to all if you want both sections and subsections linked
    %linkcolor=black,  %choose some color if you want links to stand out
%}
\usepackage{hyperref} % Liens hypertextes, signets PDF
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,colorlinks=true} 

%  \newcommand{\textcite}[1]{(#1)}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{aiaa}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

compiled with

```
pdflatex mwe.tex
bibtex mwe
pdflatex mwe.tex
pdflatex mwe.tex
```

I get the following result:

[image]

Please copy my MWE, compile it on your own computer and check the result.  If you want to get something else, please change my MWE, describe better what you need and add the changed MWE to your question.  Use bib entrys of your bib file please!